# How is it possible to get the float value from XMVECTOR? (DirectXMath)

Tags: c++, directx, directxmath

I would like to get the dot product of two 3D vectors in float. But unfortunately the result is a vector, not a float. I trued to access it's elements using `vector4_f32`, but I get an error, that it's not a member of `__m128`

```
float res = XMVector3Dot(a, b).vector4_f32[0];
```

The `[]` operator is not defined on `XMVECTOR`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access individual elements of `XMVECTOR` by using `XMVectorGetX`, `XMVectorGetY`, `XMVectorGetZ` and `XMVectorGetW`. But remember, these are more likely expensive operations as DirectXMath uses SIMD instruction set. For more info:

1: [XMVector3Dot performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542541/xmvector3dot-performance)

2: [Expensive than expected](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117943/how-can-i-access-the-members-of-xmvector)

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for DirectXMath.